# Optimising this mysql query

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I'm looking to speed up this query somehow. Possibly to the point where its acceptable to run it on a low traffic site. It takes 15+ seconds which is way too long.

Currently there are 13k rows in the table, which is approx 1 months data, however i'm expecting that monthly data to double once the site is in production. The aim is to select the top 10 gains for the last week.

there are two tables, users table and the tracker table, in the tracker table there are multiple rows for each user, at least 8 per day,  per user.

The aim of the query is to take the latest row for each user, subtract from that a value from a row inserted 1 week ago to get the amount of xp they have gained and select the top 10 highest gainers.

Table schema (which im sure could be improved too)

users table

```
id int(11) primary
rsn varchar(12) unique
joined timestamp
disabled bool
```

tracker table

```
id int(11) primary
user_id int(11) index /* Associated with the id in the users table */
timestamp timestamp
overall_rank int(11)
overall_level int(4)
overall_exp int(10)
```

And the query.

```
SELECT  `users`.`rsn` ,  `tracker`.`timestamp` , @uid :=  `tracker`.`user_id` , (
    SELECT  `overall_exp` 
    FROM  `tracker` 
    WHERE  `user_id` = @uid 
    ORDER BY  `timestamp` DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) - (
    SELECT  `overall_exp` 
    FROM  `tracker` 
    WHERE  `timestamp` >= SUBDATE( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
    AND  `user_id` = @uid 
    ORDER BY  `timestamp` ASC 
    LIMIT 1 ) AS  `gained_exp` 
FROM  `tracker` 
JOIN  `users` ON  `tracker`.`user_id` =  `users`.`id` 
ORDER BY  `gained_exp` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Explain output

```
+----+----------------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type          | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref              | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+----------------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY              | users   | index | PRIMARY       | rsn     | 14      | NULL             |    71 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY              | tracker | ref   | user_id       | user_id | 4       | surreal.users.id |   103 |                                              |
|  3 | UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY | tracker | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 11752 | Using where; Using filesort                  |
|  2 | UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY | tracker | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 11752 | Using where; Using filesort                  |
+----+----------------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: edit your post to add the output of `explain query select ...` and I'll look into how to optimise it.

Comment: have included the explain output

Comment: Can you eliminate the subqueries in any way, shape, or form?

Comment: I have done some looking into this over the past day or so, however i just cannot get my head around it. From what i've discovered it should, potentially, be possible with a join

Comment: you don't need 2 subqueries, just one is enough. In the subquery where you get the exp he had the last week you can do the substraction because you also have the last exp the user has.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN`, put the results in the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try avoiding the correlated subqueries by first finding the timestamps for today and 1 week ago for all users, then joining twice again to tracker to find the corresponding values of overall_exp before doing the calculation:

```
SELECT rsn, ts.thisweek, ts.user_id,
       last.overall_exp - previous.overall_exp AS gained_exp
FROM (SELECT user_id, MIN(timestamp) AS lastweek, MAX(timestamp) AS thisweek
      FROM tracker
      WHERE timestamp >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
      GROUP BY user_id) AS ts
INNER JOIN tracker previous
ON previous.user_id = ts.user_id AND previous.timestamp = ts.lastweek
INNER JOIN tracker last
ON last.user_id = ts.user_id AND last.timestamp = ts.thisweek
JOIN users ON ts.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY gained_exp DESC
LIMIT 10
```